# What is a slang-like phrase to use to describe someone constantly asking (in a formal or informal way) you to do something?

Tags: idioms

Somehow in my mind I had this very vague impression there is a phrase of form "xxx on" with xxx being a verb that does this.

Two examples,

My wife has been [phrase] on me to fix a broken sprinkler.

My boss has been [phrase] on me to get this done...

Comment: Using "on", there is the informal verb "to hit on" but it does not suit your examples. More suited to the examples would be **pester** or **badger** but without any "on".

Comment: **nagging** : (of a person) constantly harassing someone to do something.

Comment: asking ***for*** something.

Comment: @Ubihatt ah, I think that is what's in my mind, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What about:

- going/carrying on about
- on my back about
- on my case about

"My wife has been **carrying on** about that broken sprinkler."

"My wife has been **on my back** about fixing the broken sprinkler."

"My wife has been **on my case** about the broken sprinkler."

Answer (score 0):

to **hound**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hound)

> - To pursue relentlessly and tenaciously
> - To make repeated demands of or subject to persistent criticism

As in:

*My boss has been **hounding** me to get this done.*

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom is **the squeaky wheel gets the grease**.

From [Wikipedia](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/squeaky-wheel-gets-the-grease):

> **The squeaky wheel gets the grease** is an American proverb used to convey the idea that the most noticeable (or loudest) problems are the ones most likely to get attention. It is alternately expressed as "The squeaky wheel gets the oil".

Some people are aware of this, and just keep on complaining about something until the person they're complaining to finally takes action, if only to stop them from continuing to be annoying.

---

As for a *??? on* phrase specifically, you might be thinking of **banging on**.

From Cambridge Dictionary's entry for [*bang on*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bang-on):

> to talk about something for a long time, especially in a way that is boring to other people:
>
> *My parents are always banging on about how much better life was 20 years ago.*

Interestingly, I've never considered it to be referring to something that's boring per se, but rather to something that's repetitive and annoying for being constantly mentioned. (Although I suppose it could *also* be boring.)

Comment: How does that fit into: My wife has been [blank] etc.??

Answer (score 0):

None of the other people who have replied seem to be aware of the British expression 'to go on at' https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-go-on-at-someone

The phrase you are looking for is "My wife has been on **at** me..."

Comment: Well, there is also: to go on about, which isn't particularly British.